# Quicksort correct implemetation but with some extra comparisons

Tags: c++, recursion, quicksort

I'm trying to pull the maximum out of my Quicksort implementation. It is functionally correct and has canonical form, but I've counted some superfluous comparisons. I use the first element as a pivot:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using uint = unsigned int;

uint PartitionSub(vector<uint>& inp, uint l, uint r, uint& numOfCmp);

void QuickSort(vector<uint>& inp, uint l, uint r, uint& numOfCmp)
{
    if (r - l < 2)
        return;

    uint newPivotIdx = PartitionSub(inp, l, r, numOfCmp);

    QuickSort(inp, l, newPivotIdx, numOfCmp);
    QuickSort(inp, newPivotIdx + 1, r, numOfCmp);
}

uint PartitionSub(vector<uint>& inp, uint l, uint r, uint& numOfCmp)
{
    auto swap = [&inp](uint a, uint b)
    {
        uint buf = inp[a];
        inp[a] = inp[b];
        inp[b] = buf;
    };

    //numOfCmp += r - l; // we can use this, but ++numOfCmp just before     
                         // comparison is more clear
    uint i = l + 1;
    uint j = l + 1;

    uint p = inp[l];

    for (; j <= r; j++)
    {
        ++numOfCmp;
        if (inp[j] < p)
        {
            if (i != j)
                swap(i, j);
            i++;
        }
    }

    uint newPivotIdx = i - 1;
    swap(l, newPivotIdx);
    return newPivotIdx;
}
```

Given the input: 3,9,8,4,6,10,2,5,7,1 only 25 comparisons are required, but it does 27. I've been debugging this for three days and have no clues. If you guys see any places that should be optimized in a sense of making fewer comparisons, could you please give me some directions? As I understand, it's due to a redundant recursion pass, since the partition subroutine and the counting in it are implemented correctly.

Comment: Do not compare when `i==j` ?

Answer (score 1):

I may have spotted the problem:

```
QuickSort(inp, l, newPivotIdx, numOfCmp);
QuickSort(inp, newPivotIdx + 1, r, numOfCmp);
```

You don't need to include the pivot element in the recursion; we know it's in the correct position.  Change that first line

```
QuickSort(inp, l, newPivotIdx-1, numOfCmp);
```

You haven't displayed any debugging output, such as a trace of printing arguments on function entry, and I'm afraid I don't have time to do it myself right now.  I hope this happens to be the problem.

Comment: newPivotIdx is passed as high and low boundary into first and second branches of recursion, so it doesn't relate to the issue, anyway thank you for feedback.